# Monitor leader elections and consumer group rebalancing in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring

I need to monitor how many times leader elections and consumer group rebalancing happens in a minute. Any idea how it can be done? I have't found any metrics that allow to monitor these two things.